# My jQuery AJAX Is Not Working ( Full Uncompressed Latest Jquery Is Downloaded )

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, session

Ajax does not seem to be working for me at all, could you tell me the reason for that please? I am trying to make a chat application so I send the sender's id which is already stored from the php's session variable and the receiver which is always admin ( has an id 1 )

** THE JQUERY PART : **

```
echo '<script>
// show the modal
$("#ChatDialog").modal("toggle");
// send message
$(function() {
  $("#send").click(function(e) {
    var message = $("#message").val();
    var receiver = "1";
    var sender = "' . $id . '";

    if (message.length !== 0 & /\S/.test(message)) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        url: "send.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          sender: sender,
          receiver: receiver,
          message: message
        },
        success: function() {
          alert("success");
          $("#message").val("");
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#message").val("Hi what\'s up with my order ?");
    }
  });
});
</script>';
```

** The PHP PART **

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['USERNAME']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['message']))
    {
        require_once 'database.php';
        $sender = $_POST["sender"];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $receiver = $_POST['receiver'];

        $query = "USE " . $database;
        $select = $connect->prepare($query);
        $select->execute();
        $query = "INSERT INTO CHATS (SENDER, RECEIVER, MESSAGE) VALUES (:SENDER, :RECEIVER, :MESSAGE)";
        $sql = $connect->prepare($query);
        $data = array(
            ':SENDER' => $sender,
            ':RECEIVER' => $receiver,
            ':MESSAGE' => $message
            );
        $sql->execute($data);
    }
}
else
{
    header('location:orders.php');
}  
?>
```

Comment: `$("#message").serialize();` should be `$("#message").val()`. jQuery automatically serializes all the elements of the `data` object.

Comment: thanks for this note Barmar but it's still not working 

Comment: Check the Network tab to see if it's sending the parameters you expect.

Comment: This is clearly invalid javascript: `var sender = "' . $id . '";` did you maybe mean: `var sender = "<?php echo $id; ?>";`? or `var sender = $id;`?

Comment: admcfajn the script is already in an echo that's why I am just adding the variable id you see what I mean ?

Comment: @JalalGang You need to do like I did for you here, using `@member_name` syntax in order to ping someone directly. They also might no longer be present. Btw, check for errors for the PHP and error handling on the PDO; you might find some. You may want to edit your post to contain what the HTML is. Is that also related to how you're getting values from?

Comment: How about the obvious - is `$_SESSION['USERNAME']` really set? Have you done some basic debugging?  Check your browser's devtools, check the console - any errors? Click the network tab, is your POST actually happening?  If yes, click it to see details - was your `sender` etc data sent?  How did the server respond?   Anything in your PHP/web server logs?

Comment: I don't really know how to check all of that could you show me how please ?

Comment: 1. Temporarily remove the `$_SESSION['USERNAME']` test, and see if that works. 2. If you don't know about devtools, get researching!  :-) [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) ... 3. You are working blind without your server logs. Where they are and how to get them depends entirely where and how your environment is set up. Working with WAMP locally? Google "WAMP PHP log".  Using MacOS? Google "MacOS Apache log".  Developing on a Cpanel server? You guessed it, Google "Cpanel Apache log". Get cracking! :-)

Comment: tested removing it still not working

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST['sender']` value will always be `' . $id . '`, because of `var sender = "' . $id . '";`, which is not a value you want to insert into your database.

You mention that the sender ID is already stored in the session. Why then do you use `$_POST['sender']` to obtain the sender ID? Sounds like you want to use `$_SESSION['sender']`.

Comment: 1. no it's already within an echo statement that's why 2. that's what I mean 3. this still doesn't solve it

Comment: I do not see any `echo` statements. But what error do you experience (or otherwise undesirable outcome)?

Comment: the error is that I don't get the message inserted into database neither sender or receiver